# Regression Coefficients in terms of Individual treatment effect

Tags: regression, estimation, treatment-effect

According to the famous book “Mostly Harmless Econometrics”, the regression coefficient can be written in terms of the individual treatment effects.

Precisely, the authors state that:

> Even so, allowing for random variation in potential outcomes across
> people and for nonlinearity for a given person, regression can
> be thought of as a strategy for the estimation of a weighted
> average of the individual-specific difference, $Y_{1i}-Y_{0i}$.

($Y_{1i}$ is the potential treated outcome, and $Y_{0i}$ is the potential untreated outcome.)

Although I look over the entire book, I was not able to how the regression estimand (coefficient) can be thought a weighted average of the individual treatment effect.

So, if you know where I can find the reference related to this issue, or you can show me the derivation, please help me.

Comment: It's in the Regression Meets Matching section of chapter 3, starting with equation 3.3.4

Comment: I read the chapter and I think the conseconce is that the regression estimand is an weighted average of "covariate-specific" effects. I think, if the only reason for the variation in the effect across people is covariates, the result implies what I want know. Is my understanding correct?